# При клике на select

Tags: javascript

Есть обычный select:

```
<select name="type_id" id="type_id">
  <option value="1">Баннеры</option>
  <option value="2">Шманеры</option>
</select>
```

Как сделать так, чтоб при клике на него менялось значение `option`, но само окно со всеми `option` не показывалось?

Comment: на какое значение должно меняться при клике? если не показывать выпадающую часть, как определять что должно быть выбрано?

Comment: не понятно зачем тогда select? может просто кнопку тогда сделать?

Comment: или радиокнопками переключать значение

Answer (score 2):

Совершенно непонятно зачем это может быть нужно, но тем не менее задача разрешима. Главная проблема состоит в том, что при щелчке на `select` список будет выпадать всегда (по крайней мере, запретить это действие мне не удалось). Поэтому придётся поступить хитрее и запрятать `select` в контейнер `div`, который и будет получать события мышки. В приведённом ниже сниппете каждый щелчок на `select` выбирает в нём следующую опцию.

```js
function onClick() {
    var select = document.getElementById("select1");
    select.selectedIndex = (select.selectedIndex + 1) % select.options.length;
}
```

```css
select#select1 {
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div onclick="onClick();">
        <select id="select1">
            <option value="1">Option 1</option>
            <option value="2">Option 2</option>
            <option value="3">Option 3</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</body>
```